# Toggle selection from list with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple select boxes used for filtering data from a database.
For example select box 1:

```
<select name="team" multiple size="3">
             <option value="1">Team 1</option>
             <option value="2">Team 2</option>
             <option value="3">Team 3</option>
</select>
```

And select box 2:

```
<select name="name" multiple size="3">
             <option value="John">John</option>
             <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
             <option value="Ryan">Ryan</option>
</select>
```

Problem is once i select a value from a field i can't deselect it and i don't want to reset all filters and start allover. I would like to be able to deselect the selected option on second click, for each box ... i.e.: 1st click => select / 2nd click=> deselect.

How is the easiest way to do this?
Thank you for patience!

Comment: You can deselect an option in a multiselect by CTRL+click (or CMD+click on a Mac)

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan pointed out simple CTRL+click does it, you don't need code to do it.

Comment: this application is used by many users and they would not know that, that's why i tryied to make things more intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<select id="select1" name="team" multiple size="3">
             <option value="1">Team 1</option>
             <option value="2">Team 2</option>
             <option value="3">Team 3</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="name" multiple size="3">
             <option value="John">John</option>
             <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
             <option value="Ryan">Ryan</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
 $("#select2").val(null);
});

$("#select2").change(function(){
 $("#select1").val(null);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    $( "select" ).dblclick(function(){
        $( this ).val("");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="team" multiple size="3">
             <option value="1">Team 1</option>
             <option value="2">Team 2</option>
             <option value="3">Team 3</option>
</select>
<select name="name" multiple size="3">
             <option value="John">John</option>
             <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
             <option value="Ryan">Ryan</option>
</select>
```